# Facebook Open-graph Tag for multiple authors in Wordpress

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I've been trying to add facebook `article:author` metatag to wordpress, unfortunately I have no idea how to add it for multiple authors. This is what I've done so far and still the author's name doesn't show up in the facebook shares.

```
<meta property="article:author" content= "<?php $author = get_the_author(); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/article#properties the `article:author` contains

> An array of Facebook profile URLs or IDs of the authors for this article.

As of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories/#propertytypes-simple

> You define an array value by repeating the same meta tag name for each element of the array.

**Example**

```
<meta property="cookbook:ingredients" content="Chocolate"> 
<meta property="cookbook:ingredients" content="Sugar"> 
<meta property="cookbook:ingredients" content="Butter">
```

Make sure you define

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
```

as well.

Comment: So how should that tag go by the way? Just an array? `<meta property="article:author" content="author1, author2, author3" />` ?

Comment: I added as you've said... But the debug tool won't show the `article:author` tag at all!

Comment: Can you paste a link? And have you added the og:type property?

Comment: Yes I've added the `og:type` property and set the content to article! Still the same! I'm working for a client and I'm unable to paste any links here!

Comment: According to the code at http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wordpress-seo/trunk/frontend/class-opengraph.php the author will only be shown if the page shows a single article, and not multiple: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular Is this the case?

Comment: The page contains only one article!

Comment: Well, then without showing some code or the output of the debugger I guess it's difficult to help you then. Probably it's a configuration issue of your plugin...

Comment: Here is the snapshot: http://imgur.com/XcREWBm | The og:type is also added, but it is in the header! I added it anyway.

Comment: Ok, and where are all the other neccessary properties like `title`...? all the OpenGraph tags should go to the `<head>`

Comment: They are added by the YOAST SEO plugin.

Comment: And btw now the debugger error shows: `"Object at URL '<my url>' of type 'article' is invalid because the given value '<author's name>' for property 'article:author' could not be parsed as type 'profile'.`

Comment: Yeah, why don't you use your YOAST plugin? It supports the properties, you just need to confiure it correctly

Comment: Damn, please read my answer: Author needs to be either a FB profile_id  or the profile_url

Comment: oops! Sorry! If the example is precise I wudn't have confused.. Really sorry @tobi... Thank you! Let me check!

Comment: I have a doubt. If I add three authors, how would the og pick the right author for the article?

Comment: The plugin read the author info from the wordpress metadata. Read the code I referenced.

Comment: I don't understand... Could you ELI5 me how this works?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the Yoast support here :-/ I'm sure they have docs online

Comment: https://yoast.com/facebook-open-graph-protocol/ and https://yoast.com/social-media-optimization-with-wordpress-seo-by-yoast/

Comment: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/09/add-facebook-open-graph-meta-data-wordpress-themes/